# What determines size of app in App Store?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I'd really appreciate if anyone enlighten me about this issue.

I've an example which is detailed below, if necessary i can give more example.

This is size info about items my app is composed of:

- Size of .ipa file: 105 mb,
- Size of application file(located in *Payload folder*): 184.6 mb,

When i show package contents of application file, i've got executable and media sources whose total size amount is circa 36 mb:

- Size of executable file: 29.9 mb,
- Size of media sources(splash images, etc): circa 6 mb

Also, in *Symbols folder*(which located in the same directory with *Payload folder*) there are 2 .symbols files. Their sizes are 37.8 mb and 40.4 mb.

Finally, in App Store my application appears with size of 171 mb.

While .ipa file is much more less (105 mb), i cannot get why App Store size is so great.
Previously, my apps' size were too close to .ipa file size. However, for last couple of months there are great difference between the sizes(this also valid for updated apps, not only valid for new apps). I could not find updated statement related to this issue on Apple's documentation. If anybody clarify this issue for me or direct me any source on this issue, i'd really be thankful.

Answer (score 2):

One difference since iOS 9 is [app thinning](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html): "A variant contains only the executable architecture and resources that are needed for the target device."

Many resources not needed for a specific device may be removed, so the size downloaded to a device is based on that device.

There may also now be a difference on how thw esize is reported in the app store since there is no longer one-size fits all devices.

Additionally the upload to the app store may contain Bitcode which is not downloaded to the device.

Answer (score -1):

When you upload file your executable is not encrypted so can be packed effectively by zip. However, when you download from the App Store executable is encrypted so it cannot be compressed that good anymore, so IPA size is increased.

Comment: It does not answer my question; i am not asking about downloaded size, am asking for size that appears on App Store.

Comment: Downloaded size is the size displayed at App Store, isn't it?

Comment: This is what i'm talking about, previously they weren't the same. App Store size was much smaller than downloaded size and close to .ipa file's size. Apparently, anymore, it is too close to downloaded size. However i do not know surely, whether downloaded and app store size are supposed to be the same. Also, i've not observed any official documents that says they should be the same/close. Is there any resources you're basing on by saying this? I'm not saying it is wrong but can you direct me an official resource that verifies app store size should be the same/similar as downloaded app size?