# Big size on iOS App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, unity-game-engine

i am using Unity 5.3.1f1 and make game for iOS, after my game is done i build it to XCode. The binary archived from XCode, and generate ~65MB IPA file. Terrifically, after i upload that IPA file to the app store, it becomes larger ~150MB.

I have read this thread:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1149641/very-large-ios-build-size-unity-5.html. But in those case, their IPA file itself is large, and i already disable bitcode

Do you guys have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

By assuming you're ok with ~65MB file, i can say there is nothing you can do about it. App store shows install size of your game which is a lot larger than size of compressed IPA file.

For instance, while my game's IPA file size is ~95MB its size on app store appears as ~300MB. In case it helps, please see [my earlier question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34200494/what-determines-size-of-app-in-app-store)